# What is the name of words like 'bottle' or 'clove' that provide a singular for a counted item?

Tags: grammar, terminology

Title pretty much askes the question.  What is the term for words like 'bottle', 'cup' or 'clove' (as in clove of garlic).  Are they counters, countables, determiners...?  I swear it's on the tip of my tongue but I cannot find the correct term.

Comment: Wouldn't those be "units"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are talking about is a [measure word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_word#English), more formally known as a [numeral classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifier_%28linguistics%29).

(You could also use "counter".)